# How to prevent non-breaking spaces from being created in a contenteditable element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a contenteditable div, which creates many non-breaking spaces when words are deleted or added. This is the format of my code:

```
<div id="div" contenteditable="true">
    <span>Hello</span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

I've tried replacing non-breaking spaces on input:

```
document.getElementById("div").oninput = function() {
     document.getElementById("div").innerHTML.replace("&nbsp;","");
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the `innerHTML` to the changed text like so:

```
document.getElementById("div").oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = document.getElementById("div").innerHTML.replace("&nbsp;","");
}
```

Because as shown in this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> The original string is left unchanged

So you need to assign the result of `replace` to something.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution without any JavaScript at all: just add `white-space: pre-wrap;` or `white-space: break-spaces;` to the styles of your content editable element... and voilà, no more `&nbsp;` :)

Answer (score -1):

you have used `getElementById()`, while you are not using any `id` in your `HTM`L code, beside the above answer mentioned the `innerHTML` problem

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the id tag here, but that is not the problem.